Make error 2 when compiling MILC to run
I am part of a hpc competition my team was given the responsibility of running the benchmarks of MILC using NERSC
We done the following
$ git clone https://github.com/milc-qcd/milc_qcd.git

$ cd milc_qcd
$ git checkout develop

$ cd ks_imp_rhmc

$ cp ../Makefile .

Our Makefile is as follows
# Bonus points wil be awarded to teams who use both GNU and Intel Compilers
COMPILER=gcc
COMPILER =intel # we are told to use oneAPI
# Determine this using lscpu
ARCH= epyc
# You are NOT compiling for GPUs
WANTQUDA=false
# You can test using a serial run, but benchmark will not finish without MPI and/or OpenMP Threads
MPP =true
# You must use double-precision
PRECISION=2
OMP=true

We tried to build this file using
$ make su3_rhmd_hisq 2>&1 | tee make_logfile.log

However the build process failed and returned with the error message shown below:

